# How to tell the difference between multiple image_buttons on the same form?

Tags: 7, forms

Using FormAPI to create a simple set of three image_buttons, in the form_submit handler there is no 'op' value set in $form_state and therefore no way to tell which image_button was clicked. Is this a limitation of image_buttons?

Here's what I used to create the form, and it's bare-bones submit handler that shows no information telling me which button was clicked:

```
function cex_dash_top_icons_block_form( $form_state ) {
  $form = array();
  global $base_url;  
  $projects_icon_path  = '/'.drupal_get_path('module','cex_dash').'/Projects-icon-med.jpg';
  $reporting_icon_path = '/'.drupal_get_path('module','cex_dash').'/Reporting-icon-med.jpg';
  $help_icon_path      = '/'.drupal_get_path('module','cex_dash').'/Help-icon-med.jpg';

  $form['projects'] = array(
    '#type'  => 'image_button',
    '#value' => 'Projects Dash',
    '#src'   => $projects_icon_path,
  );

  $form['reports']  = array(
    '#type'  => 'image_button',
    '#value' => 'Analytics Dash',
    '#src'   => $reporting_icon_path
  );

  $form['help']     = array(
    '#type'  => 'image_button',
    '#value' => 'Documentation Dash',
    '#src'   => $help_icon_path
  );

  return $form;
}

function cex_dash_top_icons_block_form_submit($form_id, &$form_state) {
  _devReport( 'cex_dash_top_icons_block_form_submit: form_state is "'.print_r($form_state,1).'"' );
}
```

And no matter which button is clicked, $form_state['values'] looks like this:

```
[values] => Array(
  [projects] => Projects Dash
  [reports] => Analytics Dash
  [help] => Documentation Dash
  [form_build_id] => form-b6c762d22d0fd2360d1804ef19043c7d
  [form_token] => 4f0ce5275cc923e8fb27c305b57bf414
  [form_id] => cex_dash_top_icons_block_form
)
```

Now, in the larger `$form_state` array there is a 'clicked_button' array, but that always only has the information for the last image_button.

Do I need to create one mini-form for each image_button?

Comment: This is not a forum, but a Q&A site; updating a question   to show the adopted solution is not the best practice. If you want to show the solution you adopted (which is an answer to your question), you can write that in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue](http://drupal.org/node/206955) on drupal.org might help.

Comment: Exact: http://drupal.org/node/206955#comment-1258697

Comment: @Nikit, your link gave the final solution, which I show above.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to know which button has been clicked to take the necessary action, then you should assign a different [submission handler](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#submit-prop) to each button; see [Form buttons can define custom #submit and #validate handlers](http://drupal.org/node/144132#buttons) for more details.
Since Drupal 6, the 'op' element in the form values, corresponding to the button clicked when there are several in a form in Drupal 5.x, should no longer be relied upon and may not be present; see what reported in [The 'op' element in the form values is deprecated and should not be relied upon](http://drupal.org/node/144132#op).